# How to await for MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() results?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to await for MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() completion and get list with URIs.

When doing like this:

```
    val paths = arrayOf(
        "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Folder/Imperial Black Unit - Now You Can Pray.mp3",
        "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Folder/Lapse of Reason - Lapse of Reason - Go Away.mp3"
    )
    val uris = ArrayList<String>()

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
        applicationContext,
        paths,
        null
    ){ _, uri ->
        uris.add( uri.toString() )
    }

    println(uris)
```

I get the empty list because scanFile() function is still running.
It probably can be done with something like this:

```
    do {
        var pending = true
        if( uris.size == paths.size ) pending = false
    } while (pending)
```

But this is rather a quick fix. Sorry I really don't know Kotlin, but trying to implement Android native side feature for a Flutter app.